Using multicast with Windows WireGuard
I'm using IPMidi to multicast Midi data between machines connected through a WireGuard tunnel. The tunnel does get a handshake, but I'm unable to send the Midi data through.
I've set my allowed IPs open for the tunnels as well as 224.0.0.251/32 and ff02::fb/128 as I'd seen on another thread that allows mDNS messages but I'm not entirely sure I need it.
I also saw there is a command on Linux for enabling Multicast but I am unsure what I should add on my config on Windows.
